# Disable delete confirmation on MacOS

Tags: macos, zsh

When I delete multiple files with `rm -fr *` from the command line I get a confirmation like this:

```
zsh: sure you want to delete all 4 files in /Users/admin/build/test [yn]?
```

how to disable it for the current bash session?

My OS: MacOS Big Sur 11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `bash`.  You're using `zsh`.  Obviously.

Your question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988160/why-does-rm-f-ask-me-for-confirmation-on-zsh